# set the value of inputbox inside a data grid through VB code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, input, datagrid

I have a asp datagrid one of the column is having one input

```
     <asp:DataGrid ID="dgItem" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="TableList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PagerStyle-Visible="False">
      <Columns>

         <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Disc %">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="ListHeader"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="6%" CssClass="TdList"></ItemStyle>
         <ItemTemplate>
                <input class="Input" onkeypress="if((event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57) &amp;&amp; event.keyCode != 46 &amp;&amp; event.keyCode != 45) event.returnValue=false;"
id="txtDiscRate" style="width: 100%; text-align: right" value="0.00" name="txtDiscRate"
runat="server" onchange="checkrate();">
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateColumn>
     </Columns>
    <PagerStyle Visible="False"></PagerStyle>
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

how to set the value of that column through VB.net code
This column is the 10th cell. In the 1st cell there is a value which should be set to the 10th column

So, I've tried the following..but not working.

```
 Dim lnDiscRate As Double
 Double.TryParse(lodgGrid.Cells(1).Text, lnDiscRate)
 Dim loDiscRate As HtmlInputText
 For Each lodgGrid In dgItem.Items
   loDiscRate = lodgGrid.Cells(10).FindControl("txtDiscRate")
   loDiscRate.Value = lnDiscRate 'Not working :(
   loDiscRate.Enabled = True 'this is Working.. 
 Next
```

Pls Help!!

Got something else. when i do this

```
CType(lodgGrid.FindControl("txtDiscRate"), HtmlInputText).Value = 10 ' Working
CType(lodgGrid.FindControl("txtDiscRate"), HtmlInputText).Value = lnDiscRate ' Not Working
```

Comment: What error did you get, if any?  Have you tried setting the value without quotes? i.e.   `loDiscRate.Value = 10.00`

Comment: There is no error but the value is not changing. i will try without quotes.

Comment: No, still not working Derek. Actually i am using a variable of type double instead of "10.00". i've changed it to string also while assigning.

Answer (score 0):

Implement ItemDataBound on your DataGrid and use the following

```
Private Sub dgItem_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgItem.ItemDataBound

'Get the text value of the second cell as stated above, if you want the first use 0
Dim lnDiscRate As String
lnDiscRate = e.Item.Cells(1).Text

'set the text value of the desired input to the string found above...
CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtDiscRate"), HtmlInputText).Value = lnDiscRate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GJKH will check.. :) anyway I have managed it by putting the code in pre-init event of the page..